# Let $A\subset B$ be bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Show $\inf{A}\ge \inf{B}$.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Trying to prove the assertion by contradtion.

Let $x=\inf{A}<\inf{B}=y$.  Then $x<a\in A$, $y<b\in B$.

Since $A\subset B, a\in B, \forall a\in A$.

But since $x<y$, $\exists{a_1}\in A$ such that

$$x<a_1<y$$
This is impossible since $a_1\in B$ which means that $a_1>y$ since $y$ is the infimum.  Therefore $\inf{A}\ge \inf{B}$.

Is this proof valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost on the right track. Below I edited your proof with a few changes.

Trying to prove the assertion by contradiction.

Let $x=\inf{A}<\inf{B}=y$.  Then $x\leq a\in A$, $y\leq b\in B$.

Since $A\subset B, a\in B, \forall a\in A$.

But since $x<y$, $\exists{a_1}\in A$ such that $x\leq a_1<y$.

This is impossible because $a_1\in B$ which means that $a_1\geq y$ since $y$ is the infimum.

Therefore $\inf{A}\ge \inf{B}$.

Comment: ah yes, the two cases where the infimum could or could not be an elemnt of A.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is almost correct.

I mean almost because if $x = \inf A$ then you have $x \le a$ for all $a \in A$ and not $x < a$ as you wrote. Then you can slightly modify your argument into there exists $a_1 \in A$ such that
$$x \le a_1 < y$$ to get the contradiction.