# Question about a proof of the following: "Let $A \subset B \subset \mathbb{R}$. Prove $\inf(A) \geq \inf(B)$."

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am wondering about the following proof, reproduced below: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2063597/81560

> Let $x=\inf{A}<\inf{B}=y$.  Then $x\leq a\in A$, $y\leq b\in B$.
>
> Since $A\subset B, a\in B, \forall a\in A$.
>
> But since $x<y$, $\exists{a_1}\in A$ such that $x\leq a_1<y$.
>
> This is impossible because $a_1\in B$ which means that $a_1\geq y$ since $y$ is the infimum.
>
> Therefore $\inf{A}\ge \inf{B}$.

How do we know of the existence of $a_1 \in A$ with $x \leq a_1 < y$ since $x < y$? Otherwise, I follow the entire proof.

I guess one could approach this in the following matter: by definition of $\inf$, $A \neq \varnothing$. If $A$ is a one-element set, then $a_1 = x$. If $A$ has cardinality greater than $1$, then $x \leq a_1$. So there definitely exists an element $a_1 \in A$ with $x \leq a_1$.

But how would we know that $a_1 < y$?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't bring myself to read that long proof with all those symbols. What's wrong with this? Since $A\subset B$, every lower bound of $B$ is also a lower bound of $A$. In particular, the greatest lower bound of $B$ (aka $\inf B$) is a lower bound of $A$, and every lower bound of $A$ is $\le$ the greatest lower bound of $A$, so the greatest lower bound of $B$ is less than or equal to the greatest lower bound of $A$.

Comment: @bof Thank you so much for this explanation. It makes so much more sense than trying to sort through the wad of symbols.

Comment: If $y > x = \inf A$ then $y$ is not a lower bound so there exists as $a_1\in A$ that is $a_1 < y$. And as $x = \inf A$ then $x \le a_1 < y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up on trying to parse these symbols again and decided to just write out the proof myself. Many thanks to @bof for writing the proof out in plain English.

Recall by definition of the infimum of a set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ that

1. it must be a lower bound of $A$: for each $a \in A$, it is a value $\ell$ satisfying $\ell \leq a$.
2. it must be the greatest lower bound of $A$: for any lower bound $\ell$, $\ell \leq \inf A$.

Suppose $A \subset B \subset \mathbb{R}$.

*Claim*. Every lower bound of $B$ must be a lower bound of $A$.

Suppose $\ell_{B}$ is a lower bound of $B$. For each $b \in B$, $\ell_B \leq b$. Since $A \subset B$, we have $a \in B$ for each $a \in A$, so $\ell_B \leq a$ for each $a \in A$ as well. Hence, $\ell_B$ is a lower bound of $A$.

*Claim*. $\inf B$ is a lower bound of $A$.

This follows immediately by the prior claim, since any lower bound of $B$ (of which $\inf B$ is one of them) must be a lower bound of $A$.

Since if $\ell_A$ is a lower bound of $A$, we have $\ell_A \leq \inf A$, given that $\inf B$ is a lower bound of $A$, it follows that $\inf B \leq \inf A$. $\square$

Answer (score 1):

> How do we know of the existence of a1∈A with x≤a1<y since x<y? Otherwise, I follow the entire proof.

The definition of $\inf A$ is that if $y > \inf A$ then it is not a lower bound of $A$.  And as $y$ is not a lower bound of $A$ there exists an $a_1\in A$ where $a_1 < y$.  And as $x = \inf A$ then $x \le a_1 < y$.

(I assume the next step of the proof is to show this is a contradiction as $y = \inf B$ so $a_1 < \inf B$ means $a_1 \ne B$ contradicting that $A\subset B$.)

=======

Alternatively an intuitive proof and one more in wrapping your head around the concepts:

$A\subset B$ then if $l$ is a lower bound and less  than or equal to all elements of $B$ then it is less than or equal to all elements of $A$ as all elements of $A$ **are** elements of $B$.

So every lower bound of $B$ is a lower bound of $A$.

Well, $\inf B$ is a lower bound of $B$ so $\inf B$ is a lower bound of $A$.  And as $\inf A$ is the *greatest* lower bound of $A$, it is greater or equal to all lower bounds of $A$ included $\inf B$.

So $\inf B \le \inf A$.

Answer (score 0):

It is by the definition of $\inf$, the greatest lower bound.

For any number greater than $\inf A$, it cannot be a lower bound of $A$, so there must be some element in $A$ greater than said number.

Here, $\inf A < \inf B$, so $\inf B$ is not a lower bound of $A$. Therefore there is some $a_1 < \inf B$.

Since $\inf A$ is a lower bound, $\inf A \le a_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of intuitively, but also rather rigorously, the $\inf$ of a subset has to be at least as big as that for the superset, since you are taking the greatest lower bound of a bigger set.  That is, the $\inf$ of the superset is automatically a lower bound for the smaller set.  So, the $\inf$ of the smaller set will either be that value or something greater.

It's a bit of a mouthful, but actually obvious.